# SQL Server Update TOP by date entered

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table [occ] **without PK or timestamps**.

These are the columns

```
on_date  type_id  price_id  processed
```

I need to update 50 records to processed = 1 every X minutes.

My issue is that the code below acts a bit randomly and may update newer records and leave out older ones, creating huge sync problems in my backend

```
UPDATE TOP (50) occ 
SET processed = 1 
FROM occ
```

How could I make sure that my TOP 50 updated records are the oldest evey time?

Thank you

Comment: ' have a table [occ] without PK or timestamps.' sorry there is your problem I imagine. SQL does not guarantee any particular order of returned records, unless you specify the order.  I would recommend giving the table an identity column then order by id desc -

Answer (score 0):

By adding `Where` and Order By clause like this - `Order By on_date` in your query.

```
UPDATE TOP (50) occ 
SET processed = 1 
FROM occ
WHERE processed = 0
Order By on_date
```

Comment: on_date is not timestamp. It cannot be used to set the age of the record

Comment: @PanosPlat: Then which is the unique key in your table ?

Comment: he hasn't got a unique key or timestamp, it's in the original question, he's asking how to order by timestamp without a timestamp - actually if you know how to do that, I'd have learnt something new

Comment: I have added a datetime field as timestamp buy SQL Server throws an error when I execute the above query. If I remove the ORDER BY it passes OK. Why??

Comment: syntax errorI reckon you cannot update using ORDER By. I have used a cte instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that unless you store the timestamp or a sequential ID (such as an identity field) - you can not guarantee that TOP 50 returns the the oldest 50 records.  SQL might seem to often return the earliest records first in such cases, but this is not a guaranteed or predictable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Create one ID(Identity Column) for every row added in the table and and use Order By Id in your Query

```
UPDATE TOP (50) occ 
SET processed = 1 
FROM occ
WHERE processed = 0
Order By Id
```